# How does the groups parameter in torch.nn.conv* influence the convolution process?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to convolve a multichannel tensor with the same single channel weight.
I could repeat the weight along the channel dimension, but I thought there might be an other way.

I thought the groups parameter might do the job. However I don't understand the documentation. 
That's why I want to ask how the groups parameter influences the convolution process ?

Comment: are you interested in conv2d?

Comment: yes, but I guess the same logic applies to conv1d, conv3d

Answer (score 1):

Just minor tips since I never used it.

Group parameter multiplies the number of kernels you would normally have. 
So if you set group=2, expect 2 times more kernels.

The definition of [conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d) in PyTorch states group is 1 by default.

If you increase the group you get the depth-wise convolution, where each input channel is getting specific kernels per se.

The constraint is both in and out channels should be dividable by group number.

I think in Tensorfolow you can read the documentation of `SeparableConv2D` since this is what is equivalent when group>1.